# When is WebSocket.onmessage triggered?

Tags: javascript, websocket

(1) Open a WebSocket connection.

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

(2) When connection is established, send a message which will trigger a blob sent back in response.

```
ws.onopen = function () {
    ws.send('1000000');
}
```

(3) Is `onmessage` triggered when the response begins or is complete?

```
ws.onmessage = function () {
    // Has the entire blob arrived or has the download just begun?
}
```

Comment: When it's received, or - when complete. If it were called when the response begins, we'd have much more work to do to determine when the message  arrives - which would make websockets lower lever rather than higher level messaging abstraction.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to leave that as an answer so that I can vote for it?

Comment: There's a much better answer posted right now, so feel free to accept it, it should help other people with the same question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [W3C spec for the WebSocket API](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) says that a `message` event should be dispatched "when a WebSocket message has been received":

> When a *WebSocket message has been received* with type *type* and data *data*, the user agent must queue a task to follow these steps:

> ...

> 2. Let *event* be an event that uses the `MessageEvent` interface, with the event type `message`, which does not bubble, is not cancelable, and has no default action.

> ...

> 5. Dispatch *event* at the `WebSocket` object.

To understand what is meant by "when a WebSocket message has been received," we must consult [RFC 6455, "*The WebSocket Protocol*"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). In WebSockets, participants send *messages* that are contained in one or more *frames*:

> After a successful handshake, clients and servers transfer data back
> and forth in conceptual units referred to in this specification as
> "messages".  On the wire, a message is composed of one or more frames.

Once you understand that, you can understand [section 6 of RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-6), which defines the phrase "*A WebSocket Message Has Been Received*":

> **If the frame comprises an unfragmented
> message** (Section 5.4), it is said that *_A WebSocket Message Has Been
> Received_* with type /type/ and data /data/.  If the frame is part of
> a fragmented message, the "Application data" of the subsequent data
> frames is concatenated to form the /data/.  **When the last fragment is
> received** as indicated by the FIN bit (frame-fin), it is said that *_A
> WebSocket Message Has Been Received_* with data /data/...

Assuming that sever-side library's `send` method treats its argument as a "message", the specification requires that the client wait for the receipt of the entire message before firing the `message` event.

A server-side API that allowed streaming (e.g., it kept the message incomplete and withheld the FIN bit until some kind of `finish` method was called) would not cause the client to fire the `message` event until the message concluded.